# it is prossible to run qtmobility on arm platform

Tags: arm, gstreamer, multimedia, qt-mobility

i was compiled qtmobility modules multimedia to arm（using QtE4.8.1 arm-linux-gcc）,also i put the lib files and plugin files in my arm linux file system。when i run a demo videoplayer （run well in desktop）there get a error like ：

no service found for - "com.nokia.qt.mediaplayer" is it possible to run qtmobility multimediakit on

so i put gstreamer libs in /lib directory which compiled by arm-linux-gcc.also error occured

(:267): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_ref: assertion `object != NULL' failed
(<unknown>:267): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set: assertion`G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
(:267): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_ref: assertion `object != NULL' failed
(<unknown>:267): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_link_pads_full: assertion`GST_IS_ELEMENT (dest)' failed
(:267): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_set_state: assertion `GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed
(<unknown>:267): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_set_state: assertion`GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed
(:267): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_unlink: assertion `GST_IS_ELEMENT (dest)' failed
(<unknown>:267): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_bin_remove: assertion`GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed
(:267): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_obje

any help ？
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You seemed to have something messed up. Do you know that GStreamer has native qt bindings?